# Where to find the properties of FrameNode (2.93.5)

Tags: materials, node-editor, shaders

According the manual it is possible to add text in the node editor using the frame node
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/controls/nodes/frame.html?highlight=frame%20node

When I place the node "Frame" from the add menu I cant find this menu
[image]

Where is this in Blender?

Comment: select your frame and open the Sidebar tool ("N" on your keyboard)

Comment: Thanks @Emir How do I get text into it? Coz now I enter some text into the Text field below Shrink press return and nothing happens. I tried to paste a txt file into it and even a path??

Sorry for me being not so good with this :-)

Comment: If you wanna change the name of a frame, you need to writte that inside the Label area not the Name area.

Comment: If you want to use the Text field, you first need to create a Text data block in the Text Editor. Then you can select that data block from the Text field for the Frame node.

Comment: THUMBS UP!!! Thansk for your help :-) Fixed it

Comment: @Emir Can you please post your comments as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the frame and open the sidebar by pressing <kbd>N</kbd>, here you will see the option and you just need to add a name inside the Label section.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the comments

- If you have node wrangler enabled, you can frame one or more nodes by selecting all of the nodes you want to frame and typing <kbd>Shift</kbd>–<kbd>P</kbd>
- If you have a frame selected, you can type <kbd>F2</kbd> and add a label in the popup box.  The label acts as the frame title and is text that will appear at the top center of the frame.
- If you create a text block and enter its name into the *Text* property of the frame you end up with text starting in the upper left of the frame.
- The frame's properties are found in the side panel in the *Node* tab (Shortcut to toggle the sidepanel visibility is <kbd>N</kbd>)

Here's a frame around a material with a label and a text property:

[image: Frame around material showing label and text property]

Here are the settings for the frame:

[image: Sidebar showing Node tab with frame selected]

Here is the text editor showing the text that appears in the sidebar.  Notice that the name in the text field of the text editor is the same as in the text field in the frame's properties:

[image: Text editor showing the frame text]

The manual documents the various properties in the [Frame Node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/controls/nodes/frame.html) entry.

Comment: [What to do with questions which have been answered in comments?](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/436/what-to-do-with-questions-which-have-been-answered-in-comments)

Comment: @brockmann I don't think the comments fully answered the question.  No comment mentioned the use of F2 to set the frame label, for example.

Comment: @MartyFouts

It would be nice to point out that the text editor can be found inside the "scripting"  tab